# Add an option to a g:select after it loaded elements dynamically?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a select like this:

```
<g:select style="width: 500px;;" name="ftp" value="${ftpResource.host[0]}"
              from="${ftpResource.host}"
              optionKey="${ftpResource.id}"
              keys="${ftpResource.id}" />
```

but I want to add a message in the drop down list and then more information, like:

```
ftp1
ftp2
ftp3
this message
ftp kind 1
ftp kind 2
ftp kind 3
```

I tried this:

```
from="${[ftpResource.host, 'Message', ftpkindResource.host]}"
```

but it displays it inline, How can I do that?

(and taking a chance of this post, with property 'keys' can I set the Ids live values to send them in params for each option?)

Comment: Does `from="${[*ftpResource.host, 'Message', *ftpkindResource.host]}"` work?

Comment: No, the page doesn't load

Comment: Why it doesn't load? What's wrong? Because if `ftpResource.host` and `ftpkindResource.host` are arrays, construction suggested by tim_yates should work.

Comment: it loads this way: 
ftp1,ftp2,ftp3 (all this in one line)
this message  (all this in another line)
ftp kind 1, ftp kind 2, ftp kind 3 (all this in another line)

And I don't know if it will have problems with their values and I want them to display vertical